# asp.net core attribute adapter overwrites the server error message

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding

I have a custom attribute that based on some conditions I display a message with dynamic values taken from the class (ex: For '{1}' the value has to be less than '{0}'.). And I wanted to validate also on the client so I have created an attribute adapter but because the values can be changed I used some replacers like "__val1__" and "__val2__" and the client will replace the values with the correct values.

Now I have discovered that if the client is not validated and the validation fails on server instead of "For 'XXX' the value has to be less than 'YYY'." I get the message "For '__val1__' the values has to be less than '__val2__'." and this is the message that I place for the client validation but it seems that also the server error is changed to this one.

Is there a way to tell asp.net core that the adapter should not overwrite the server error message?

Comment: Do you want to customize the model verification on the client side? If so, and you just want to change the error message on the client side, please refer to the official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-client-side-validation

Comment: It was done using that as an example, just that my message has two parameters taken from the same class where I place the attribute. And I need to have both client and server validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging I have found out that when the Adapter is executed for the server validation the type of the context is ModelValidationContext

```
public override string GetErrorMessage(ModelValidationContextBase validationContext)
  {
     var modelContext = validationContext as ModelValidationContext;

     if (modelContext == null)
     {
        return GetErrorMessage(validationContext.ModelMetadata, "__val1__", "__val2__");
     }
     else
     {
        var model = modelContext.Container as <Class>;
        var val1 = //get the real value from the model;
        var val2 = //get the real value from the model
        return GetErrorMessage(validationContext.ModelMetadata, val1, val2);
     }
  }
```